# Printing reversely a circular single linked list

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I am practicing questions randomly from my textbook and i came over this question and was not able to get it done.

How can I print a circular single linked list in reverse order? For example : If the list has elements: 1 2 3 , It should print them 3 2 1

Note it's a circular linked list and no parameters should be in the method.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried recursion?

Comment: DO you have any CODE we can work with?

Comment: @Tdorno   void printReverse() {
    Node<E> temp = list;
    if (temp.getNext() == null) { 
      System.out.println(temp.getInfo());
    }
    printReverse(temp.getNext());
  }
}

Comment: @user2272227 but by definition, shouldn't getNext()==null always be false if it's a circular linked list?

Comment: @user2272227 How are you choosing the start of the list?

Comment: @rob the list is always instanciated   Node<E> list; which is pointing to the first node.

Comment: @FDinoff   Node<E> list; the name of the node at the start is called list.

Comment: @user2272227 right, but the last node in a circular list points to the first node (otherwise it wouldn't be circular), so getNext() should always return a non-null value as long as the list contains at least one element.

Comment: @rob exactly, its circular.

Comment: And now we've come full-circle (pun intended).  temp.getNext() should never return null, so you can't test for that.

Comment: @rob so how would this be solved?

Comment: Can the list be modified?

Comment: You can recursion and test for temp.getNext() == start instead (or, rather, temp.getNext() != start), as Harold mentioned in his answer/comment, and as Marvo answered in his solution.

Comment: You don't absolutely need to use recursion.  You could also put every entry on a stack, and test each node against the first entry in the stack.  Then when you're done populating the stack, you'd pop off each entry and print it until the stack is empty.  It'd probably use less memory than recursion, and it would use heap rather than the program's stack, so it might be better.  But for crazy long lists, it'd be a problem.  Reversing the links during print is another way and would use less memory, but that assumes nobody else needs to use the list at the time you're printing.

Comment: @Marvo marvo, you gave me a lovely solution down, if it was to be done using the stack way? would you have time to right the code for me to test and see how it works? If not, it's alright. you've done a lot!

Comment: Stack approach has been added as another answer.

Comment: You could reverse the list, then print the list while undoing the reverse, similar to the C++ code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77574724/3282056), but checking getting back to the head node instead of null.

Answer (score 3):

In the base case (start node is equal to next node), print the current node. Otherwise, recurse on the next node and then print the current node.

Note this uses linear space because of the stack, but this is optimal since you have no back pointers.

Comment: that works for circular single linked list?

Comment: Change the base case to be next node != head

Comment: Oh, I missed that it's circular. Edited according to @RonDahlgren.

Comment: @HaroldR.Eason bro, my linkedlist has no front/back implemented, that's the challenge in the question.

Comment: You can make the recursive function be seeded by the start node. I.e, you call `printInReverse(list, list)`, the first parameter is the start node, the second parameter is the current node in the list. Or even simpler, start by making a global variable called `start`. Either of these ways, your recursive function will know what the start node is.

Comment: @HaroldR.Eason i just read the textbook question, no parameters for the method.

Comment: Then can you use a global variable instead?

Comment: @HaroldR.Eason global variable for the start of the list? already have called list.

Comment: Yes, a global variable for the start of the list. If the method has no parameters at all, you have to encode the call stack in memory...

Answer (score 2):

Here's a possible solution using recursion, the printing method doesn't receive any parameters:

```
public class ReversePrinter {

    private Node<?> head;
    private Node<?> current;
    private boolean first = true;

    public ReversePrinter(Node<?> head) {
        this.head = head;
        this.current = head;
    }

    public void printReverse() {

        if (current == null) {
            return;
        } else if (current == head) {
            if (!first) return;
            first = false;
        }

        Node<?> previous = current;
        current = current.getNext();
        printReverse();
        System.out.println(previous.getInfo());

    }

}
```

Use it like this:

```
ReversePrinter printer = new ReversePrinter(nodeHeadOfList);
printer.printReverse();
```

For the example in the question, it will print on the console:

```
3
2
1
```

Comment: this gives me a exception when running.

Comment: Post the code with the list you used to test it and the full stack trace

Comment: And by the way: the code in my answer was tested and works correctly, if there's an exception it's probably because the list you used was not properly constructed, start by checking that

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
class Node {
    int data;
    Node next;
    public Node getNode() ...
    public String toString() ...
}

public class CircularList {

    private Node list;

    public void printReverse() {
        final Node head = this.list;
        printReverseRecurse(list, head);
        System.out.println(list.toString());
    }

    private void printReverseRecurse(Node node, Node head) {
        if (node != head) {
            printReverseRecurse(node.getNext(), head);
            System.out.print(node.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

After editing, I forgot to pass the `head` reference to the private method.

Comment: thnx for the effort but the question wants it solved without parameters in the method;/

Comment: Yeah, that'd be useful info for the question. I'll edit.

Comment: final Node head = node;
what do you mean by node here? you mean the start of the list?

Comment: Yes, you're right.  I'll fix that.

Comment: printReverseRecurse(node);
        System.out.println(node.toString()); for these, i replace node with list correct? or head?

Comment: Yes, sorry.   I should have compiled this and run it.  =)

Comment: Note that I also pass `head` to the private method, too.  In the public method, you can print either `list` or `head`; they're the same thing.

Comment: you tried the code actually?

Comment: oh yeh ok, but what i don;t understand is why 2 methods? each printing? won't we have 2 prints now for everything?

Comment: The first method starts things off.  Because of the circular nature of the list, the outer method retains the starting point of the printing.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a non-recursive approach using a stack on the heap instead of the program stack.  Should use less memory than the recursive approach.

```
class Node { 
    private int data;
    private Node next;
    public Node getNode() { ... }
    public String toString() { ... }
}

public class CircularList {

    private Node list;

    public reversePrint() {
        Stack<Node> stack = new Stack<Node>();

        // First, put all the entries in the stack
        Node node = list;
        do {
            stack.push(node);
            node = node.getNext();
        } while (node != list);

        while (!stack.empty()) {
            System.out.print(stack.pop());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: is there any other alternative to break? we cant use it.

Comment: also, it gives errors for the for each method, it says it can only be used for arrays or iterable.

Comment: Sorry about that.  Edited.

Comment: is there something to use instead of do?

Comment: i cant use it and the first while is strange?

Comment: We cannot use while first because it is a circular list. We assigned the first node in the list as 'node', so if we execute the while loop, node != list condition is true and the loop immediately breaks. We move the node pointer to the next node in do{}, and then keep checking the condition